# Change color with this

Tags: javascript

Why isnt this working?

```
sup.farba=function() {       
     this.style.color="blue";
};

function ahoj() {
     sup=document.getElementById("aaa");
     sup.farba();
}
```

Comment: My question is, why do you think it should work?

Comment: What doesn't work about it? What happens instead of what you expect? Do you get an error message in your javascript console? Because I'm betting you do, and that error message may help explain why it doesn't work...

Answer (score 2):

the function defined in `sup.farba` doesn't know what "`this`" is.

Try:

```
function ahoj() {
    sup = document.getElementById("aaa");
    sup.style.color = "blue";
}
```

Much easier than trying to call another function from a function when not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

`this` isn't what you think it is, you can't just use dot notation and expect the functions to be chainable to some random variable.

Looks like using `bind`, `apply` or `call` would be easier for this example

```
farba = function() {       
     this.style.color="blue";
};

function ahoj() {
     var sup = document.getElementById("aaa");
     farba.apply(sup, []);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is: because that's not how it works.

```
sup = document.getElementById('aaa');
```

This overwrites `sup`... You can't access functions that were on `sup` before just because the variable has the same name!

Try this:

```
function farba(newcol) {
    this.style.color = newcol;
}
function ahoj() {
    var sup = document.getElementById('aaa');
    farba.call(sup,'blue');
}
```